# Rewrite the url or encrypt the url after getting the query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

Here is the scenario, I am using the query string to verify the user's position to show or invisible some function. But I am stuck on a problem with rewriting the URL of the website or encrypting it. My method is to pass two query strings to another page from the previous page. It works perfectly for me but I found out it is not secure. So I decided to rewrite the URL from
https://localhost:44392/Web/StaffDetailsPage.aspx?EmpID=E000001&currentEmpID=000001 to https://localhost:44392/Web/StaffDetailsPage.aspx

This is because the end-user may change the query string on the URL. For example, an admin with EmpID=123 and normal employee with EmpID=456, if the normal employee changes his EmpID to admin EmpID in the URL and press enter, the page will load again and then he will have the power to change something that an admin only can do. I know that my method may be a mistake but I only know this method to pass a value from a page to another page

Is there any way to rewrite the URL after I get the query string in the protected void Page_Load, I am using c# and HTML language(asp.net).

Please help me if anyone knows about this and sorry for my bad English

Comment: What problem does rewriting the URL solve exactly?

Comment: What does "I found out it is not secure" mean?   It looks like you are using HTTPS, so the URL is encrypted in transit.   Are you worried about it being visible on the screen?  Are you worried about it getting into referrers when users click on links?  Are you worried about data in browser cache?

Comment: What web server and backend programming language are you using to implement all this?

Comment: @Llama I have searched for some examples but I do not really understand what it saying. I am not sure the rewriting url should be code on the page or the previous page. How it works

Comment: @StephenOstermiller What I am scared about is that the end-user will change the query string. This is because I have a function that is to check their position using the EmpID query string. If they change the value of the query string might be logged in as another user. I am using c# and HTML (asp.net) language for doing all this

Comment: @Llama can you suggest a better link or other methods for the URL encryption or rewrite the URL

Comment: If you are worried about the user changing the query string, it doesn't sound like encrypting it is the right solution.  It sounds like you want to verify the identify of the user by having them log in and then make sure that that user has permission to modify whatever it is

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I will verify it using the value of the query string (EmpID) and that is why I want to rewrite the URL so that the end-user is not able to see the query string and make changes. For example, an admin with EmpID=123 and normal employee with EmpID=456, if the normal employee changes his EmpID to admin EmpID in the URL and press enter, the page will load again and then he will have the power to change something that an admin only can do. I know that my method maybe is a mistake but I only know this method to pass a value from a page to another page

Comment: The current employee id should not be coming from the query string. It should come from the logged in session.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I did not use the login session for the Login part. I just use SQL to read the data and verify using if else statement. If the password is correct so that the page will forward to other page with the query string on the url

Comment: You need to verify the password on both pages then.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like you want authentication and authorization, not URL rewriting. The latter offers no security at all.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for the suggestion. I might know how to avoid the scenario happening using your suggestion but maybe it is the wrong method. I will use query string(EmpID) and the user name to verify whether the password is same or not. If it is not same, then will jump out to the login page and ask the end-user to login again

Comment: @Llama Actually my method is not correct but I do not know how to use login session, so  I use query string to pass the value